# How to immediately see that $2-\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}\le2-\frac1{n+1}$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

My question concerns the following proof:

Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^2\le2-1/n$ for every $n$.

*Proof.* Clearly this holds for $n=1$. Assume it holds for some $n\ge1$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}1/k^2\le2-1/n+1/(n+1)^2=2-\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}\le2-1/(n+1)$. The proof is complete.

So, my question is how does one immediately see that $$2-\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}\le2-\frac1{n+1}\ ?$$ Is there a quick logical way to surmise that the expression on the left must be less than or equal to the expression on the right or is there a bit more exploration required to see that this is true? (i.e. plugging in a few values, etc.)

Comment: $$\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}=\frac{n^2+n+1}{n(n+1)^2}>\frac{n^2+n}{n(n+1)^2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{n(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to
$$\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$$
Since $n+1>0$, we can cancel it:
$$\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)} \ge 1$$
Since $n(n+1)>0$, this is equivalent to
$$(n+1)^2-n \ge n(n+1)$$
which you can see to be true by expanding both sides.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq 1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{(k-1)k}$$
and since $\frac{1}{(k-1)k}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$, the last sum is a telescopic sum and
$$ S_n \leq 1+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=2-\frac{1}{n} $$
as wanted.

Comment: So in your final step you substituted $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for $\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$. So is the idea that we are assuming that since the maximum value of $\frac{1}{k-1}$ is $1$ we are guaranteed $1\ge \frac{1}{k-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$2-\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}\le2-\frac1{n+1}\ \implies\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}\ge\frac{1}{n+1}$$ Rewriting the equation:
$$\frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+1)}-\frac{n}{n(n+1)}}{n+1}\ge\frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}}{n+1}\ge\frac{1}{n+1}\implies1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\ge1$$This is true for $n\ge1$